# Fix random seed in Neo4j

Tags: random, neo4j, cypher, random-seed

I wonder how you would fix the seed of a random number generator in Neo4j in order to make reproducible tries for development purposes. For instance, how would you fix the seed in the following example so that it always yields the same output?

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:KNOWS]->() 
WHERE rand() < 0.25
RETURN p LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked and I can confirm this is not supported at the moment.
[Implementation-wise](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/9dfc52d2b7f1b196ac07ae3e51f9dc43fd84043f/community/cypher/runtime-util/src/main/java/org/neo4j/cypher/operations/CypherFunctions.java#L432), the function relies on [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#setSeed-long-) which does even support custom seeds.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on possible workarounds?

Comment: The only workaround I can think of is to create your own Cypher function. See a simple example here: https://github.com/fbiville/neo4j-join-user-function.
See the docs there: https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/extending-neo4j/functions/